# How to perform a zoom of an image with Magick.Net

Tags: c#, graphics, imagemagick

I want to zoom an Image with Mouse event but I can't find a efficient solution.

if I use `image.Scale(new MagickGeometry(newWidth, newHeight));` the process is very slow when I increase the size of the zoom.

Is there a better way?

**Update to explain better the problem**

For example the control PictureBox does this in a good way with this instruction  `g.DrawImage(image, ScaledRectangle);` .
Here image is the original image with original size and ScaledRectangle keep the location of the image in the container and the new size. This is fast.
I would like to know how to do this without a PictureBox, with Magick.Net.

Comment: AFAIK apps "cheat": during the zoom they use a fast but low-quality scale algorithm (nearest neighbor or linear), and when the zoom stops they replace that last instance with a good quality zoom at the final scale.

Comment: I don't think so. How can we do this with Mouse's events? I think they elaborate only the visible part of the image or there is some function that perform scaling in most efficient way.